# Abstract Class -- How to specify return of generic list

Tags: c#, generics, abstract-class

I am having some difficulty with this. I have an abstract class, and I would like to add a public abstract method for its inheritors to implement. The challenge is that the method should return a generic list of classes that implement a totally different abstract class (NotifyingDatabaseObject).

I'd like to do something like the following, but it won't compile:

```
public abstract IList<T> GetList(int? id) where T : NotifyingDatabaseObject;
```

And, of course, if I replace "T" with "NotifyingDatabaseObject", it will require the inheriting classes to return that abstract class instead of concrete ones.

Any direction on how I can accomplish this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want each subclass of your base class to return a *particular* subtype of `NotifyingDatabaseObject`. In this case you should add a type parameter to the base class and have each subtype specify which subtype of `NotifyingDatabaseObject` they return:

```
public abstract class MyAbstractClass<T>
    where T : NotifyingDatabaseObject
{
    public abstract IList<T> GetList(int? id) ;
}

public class MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass<NotifyingDatabaseObjectChildClass>
{
    public override IList<NotifyingDatabaseObjectChildClass> GetList(int? id)
    {
        return new List<NotifyingDatabaseObjectChildClass>();
    }
}
```

Note the existing answer does not do this - it requires each subtype to support returning a list of *any* subtype of `NotifyingDatabaseObject`, not just one in particular. In this case the only possible implementation is to return an empty list (or null, or throw an exception, or loop infinitely), since the implementing classes have no general way of constructing a value of type `T`.

Comment: You are right -- it does need to return a particular subtype. Let me look into this, and I'll modify things as necessary. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If the returning type has no relation to the abstract or the concrete class, you can use a type parameter on the method, like:

```
public abstract IList<T> GetList<T>(int? id) where T : NotifyingDatabaseObject;
```

The concrete class would be something like:

```
class MyConcreteClass : MyAbstractClass
{
    public override IList<NotifyingDatabaseObjectChildClass> GetList<NotifyingDatabaseObjectChild>(int? id)
    {
        return new List<NotifyingDatabaseObjectChildClass>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Compiled and tested! ;) The only drawback is having to pass the type once again when calling the method: `var mylist = concrete.GetList<NotifyingDatabaseObjectChild>(10);` That's because it cannot infer the type from the usage.

Comment: Thanks - this seems to be working quite well! I'm going to have to run back and read the generics manual again.

Comment: Ok this will compile but this is not the intention, since `NotifyingDatabaseObjectChild` is a type parameter, not a concrete type. Returning an empty list is the only possible implementation in this case since the implementor has no other information about `T`. In that case you might as well move the implementation to the base class.

Comment: He never said the returning type should be concrete: `the method should return a generic list of classes that implement a totally different abstract class`, but, if that was the case, we could add the constraint to the abstract class: `where T : NotifyingDatabaseObject, new();`

Comment: There is nothing this overridden version could do that could not be done in the base class. This approach will only work if the OP wants each subclass to perform a different generic construction, which is extremely unlikely.